# Why 'sub rsp,0xa0' when come into a function

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, disassembly

I write a small C program just for fun:

```
struct A {
    int data[64];
};

struct A good(int x, int y) {
    struct A a;
    a.data[x] = y;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    struct A a;
    a = good(10,11);
}
```

Compile and disassemble it by commands:

```
$ gcc good.c -g --no-stack-protector
$ gdb -batch -ex 'disassemble good' ./a.out
Dump of assembler code for function good:
   0x0000000000001129 <+0>: endbr64 
   0x000000000000112d <+4>: push   rbp
   0x000000000000112e <+5>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000001131 <+8>: push   rbx
   0x0000000000001132 <+9>: sub    rsp,0xa0         <- this line confuse me, why 0xa0?
   0x0000000000001139 <+16>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x118],rdi
   0x0000000000001140 <+23>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x11c],esi
   0x0000000000001146 <+29>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x120],edx
   0x000000000000114c <+35>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x11c]
   0x0000000000001152 <+41>:    cdqe   
   ...
```

Why there is such instruction `sub rsp,0xa0`? and why the value is `0xa0`? (`int data[64]` should take 0x100 memory space)

Gcc version is:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
```

Architecture is:

```
$ arch
x86_64
```

Updated:
After adding compile flag `-mno-red-zone`, 0xa0 is changed to 0x118, almost understandable.

Comment: Which `gcc` version, which architecture?

Comment: Think about where local variables are stored, how many you have, and the size needed. Did you calculate 0xa0 into decimal?

Comment: Indeed it is because of red zone, when I add flag ```-mno-red-zone```, 0xa0 is changed to 0x118, and considering the alignment, it is almost understandable.